# Unable to get static class variable from C# class into VB.NET class

Tags: c#, vb.net, static-members

c# class:

```
public class AClass<T> where T : INterFace
{
  public static float m_var = 0.91F;
...
}
```

VB.NET class

```
Public Class AnotherClass
...
Public ReadOnly Property V As Single
Get
   Return AClass(Of XX).m_var
End Get
End Property
End Class
```

XX is a class (that implements INterFace)

Not sure why I can't see this - I get an error:
"`m_var is not a member of AClass(Of XX)`"

I also tried it with the c# version:

```
public class AClass<T> where T : INterFace
    {
      private const float m_var = 0.91F;
public static float VV { get { return m_var ; } }// change name in VB as needed
    ...
    }
```

Comment: I believe you did not show us something important.

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine, note the brackets on [INterface] since it's a reserved word in VB (not case sensitive like C#)

**C#**

```
public interface INterface
{
}

public class AClass<T> where T : INterface
{
    public static float m_var = 0.91F;
}
```

**VB**

Add reference to C# project

```
Imports MyCSharpNamespace

Public Class AnotherClass

    Public ReadOnly Property V As Single
        Get
            Return AClass(Of XX).m_var
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Public Class XX
    Implements [INterface]


End Class
```

Comment: Thank you, I made up the words... but this is exactly what I wrote in my question, and for some reason it simply doesn't work. I can't figure out why.

Comment: can you post the source for your XX class as well ?

Comment: Are you refering to the correct AClass ? Use F12 and check the object inspector, the only way I can get your error is by renaming or removing the m_var or making it private instead of public

Comment: I am sorry, what is the "object inspector" ? As for the contents of the class XX, there is nothing in it (other the fact that it implements the required interface) that is relevant; I even created "(Of T)" and allowed VB to create a class T for me, empty, but it gave me the same error (after adding the required interface - which may or may not be relevant). And there is nothing in the C# class that should cause problems either... I shouldn't create an object of it, that's why I wanted a static, it is a Node in a Tree and from outside I only call the tree.

Comment: Ok, never mind, the problem is most likely in the AClass class since it should have the m_var property. Check that it has a m_var property and that is is public

Comment: As it is written... And, as I showed above, creating a public property instead of a public variable didn't help at all.

Comment: just to get this straight, you have one solution with one vb project and one c# project ? And the vb project has a reference to the c# project. The vb source does an import of the c# namespace ?

Comment: Yes, it has a reference, and also (for ease of typing) an import of the namespace. There are other things in the C# project that the VB project is using, and they work fine. It is just this static element that I can't seem to access. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Clean solution and rebuild, i'm at a loss